# Possible to use GroupBy in ElasticSearch querystring?

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, query-string

I have a few records in my elasticsearch collection and i want to use a GroupBy aggregation in elasticsearch querystring.

I want to know if it is possible, because i tried to google it always give result about [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html.)

i want to use [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html) something like this in the query string , which can 
give me records in the group.

For i.e.

```
http://localhost:9200/_all/tweets/_count?q=user:Pu*+user:Kim*
```

This will give me count of all the records which has name starts from **Pu** and **Kim**,

But i want to know that how many records are there has name starting with **Pu** 
and **Kim**,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aggregations need to be specified in addition in the search request, you cannot specify them as part of a query string query.

You could also just execute two queries to find out this particular requirement...

Comment: Can you please give me an example for the same  ? I want to do this using Php Curl . .